# Download public file from Dropbox using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dropbox-api

as written in the title, I'd like to download a public file of Dropbox using VB.NET.
Obviously I'm not able to do it using WebClient, so I searched some Dropbox API. The problem is that I don't understand as well all those libraries (also because of thirdy parties).

There are a lot of things, like login, upload, file managing, ... while I'd like just the capability to download a file of Dropbox from a given URL.

How can I do it?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.  Also, why can't you use `WebClient` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use WebClient?
I use this code in C#, and it works perfectly. You can try similar code in VB.NET. Just make sure the file is shared.

```
string onlinePath = @"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s.....&dl=1"; // make sure you get the download path in this form
string downloadedFile=@"C:\..."; // file to download into
try
{
    using (System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
         Client.DownloadFile(onlinePath, downloadedFile);
    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("File not found");
}
```

Comment: It seems to work, looks like I used a wrong link then. That's inusual anyway, I never got to work with WebClients files of cloud services.